# Facebook SDK 3.0 android code works by starting from eclipse but not in playstore app?

Tags: android, facebook, release, google-play-services

in our app we integrated Facebook with the new Facebook sdk Version 3.0.

If I start the app on my test device from eclipse everything works fine. The facebook app (or the webView if native app isn't installed) opens, logs in to Facebook calls back and publishes the post.

But if I relaease this code as an apk in google playstore, download it from there and test it, the facebook app starts, user logs in and  allows publishing, than nothing happens, no post to wall O_o.

Here's the code:

```
private void facebookLogin()
{

    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() 
      {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            if(session.isOpened())
            {


                performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO);

            }
        }
    });
}

private void performPublish(PendingAction action) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            pendingAction = action;
            if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                // We can do the action right away.
                handlePendingAction();
            } else {
                // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS));
            }
        }
    }
private void handlePendingAction() 
 {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) 
        {
            case POST_PHOTO:
                postPhoto();
                break;
            case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
                postStatusUpdate();
                break;
        }
 }
private void postPhoto() 
 {
        if (hasPublishPermission()) 
        {

            Bitmap logo = g.getLevelBitmaps()[0];
            Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), logo, new Request.Callback() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) 
                {
                    postStatusUpdate();
                    if(g.isAchievementsActivated())
                    {
                        Swarm.init(logoQuestion,3777,"831e03485c37444f9b94de8fdf2e676f");
                        SwarmAchievement.unlock(10093);
                    }
                    //Toast.makeText(logoQuestion, "Posted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE);
                }
            });
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("description", "Who know's that logo? \n" + hintQuestionText+ " posted from Videogames Logoquiz now available for Android and iOS");
            //request.setParameters(params);
            request.executeAsync();

        } 
        else 
        {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
        }
 }

private void postStatusUpdate() 
 {
        if (hasPublishPermission()) 
        {
            String question = "Who know's that logo? "+hintQuestionText+" Get Videogames Logoquiz. It's now available for iOS and Android.";
            Request request = Request
                    .newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), question, new Request.Callback() 
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(logoQuestion, "Posted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();
        } 
        else 
        {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
 }
```

The hasPublishPermission function:

```
private boolean hasPublishPermission() 
 {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
 }
```

The permissions iam asking for are:

```
private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions","user_photos");
```

In my Android Manifest I have following permissions to integrate facebook:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I'dont understand why it's working by testing but not on the same release version.

Anybody know's a solution?

Thank you all!

Comment: Have you set up the facebook app correctly? Aka the hashes you need to save at dev.facebook